# How to follow a thread in slack api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

So basically, I have created a slack command which will post a message on a channel. If user 'X' is using the slash command and posting the message in a channel. I want 'X' to be notified whenever a reply is made to that thread. It can be done by following that message manually but how to do it with Slack API.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't an option available through the Slack API to programmatically follow a thread for a user. There are a couple potential workarounds, though:

- **Guiding the User:** Create a `Follow` button on your message, which when clicked pops a modal with instructions on how to manually follow the thread. Could even put an image or gif if you felt so inclined.
- **Store and handle follows yourself:** For this approach, you would need to store your message_ts values and be able to tie following users to them. Depending on what your bot does, it may also need to start listening to new events from Slack so it can handle new thread replies.

Unless it's absolutely critical to your bot functionality, I would encourage you to just go with the first option until the need for the more complex setup reveals itself. Let Slack do the work for you and concentrate on the rest of your app.